# Iterate an array of structures in Matlab, ERROR: "Reference to non-existent field 'namefield'"

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I generate an array "AoS" of structures "str" in the following way:

```
for i = 1:iMax
    for j = 1:jMax
        str = calculatestructure();
        AoS(i,j) = str;
    end
end
```

Now, let's say tha  t the structure has two fields: str.field1, str.field2. I want to get the value of str.field1 for the Ith and Jth element of AoS, and I get the following errors according to the method used.
If I use any of the two methods, I get the **error: "Reference to non-existent field 'field1'"**

```
value = AoS(I,J).field1; % method 1
value = AoS.field1(I,J); % method 2
```

Any idea? Is there a spacial command to access an array of structures? The help shown [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/11/24/working-with-arrays-of-structures/), [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/04/22/matlab-basics-array-of-structures-vs-structures-of-arrays/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234859/array-of-structures-doing-operation-on-matrix-within-field-without-loop), is not actually usefull for this poblem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure of the output of the calculatestructure() ? I tested:

```
for i = 1:10
    for j = 1:10
        str = struct();
        str.field1=1;
        str.field2=2;
        AoS(i,j) = str;
    end
end
AoS(1,1).field1
```

and I do get the field field1 of the structure at the 1,1 position in the array of structures AoS. Maybe calculatestructure() doesn't output a structure with the fields you think. Is AoS really a iMax x jMax struct array and does each element have the field1 field ?

Comment: actually the structure come from a file. I noticed that if I save it as an ".mat" file, i can access it without problems, but if I save it as a ".m" file, I can acce it using the graphical interface, but not from the code... maybe I should change the title and the description of the question...